# Change Bootstrap 4 checkbox size

Tags: bootstrap-4

Is there a way to change Bootstraps 4 beta checkbox size to a bigger one?

I almost tried altering styles but this didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: I know this might be a bit moot now that Bootstrap 4 is long out of beta, but why do most of the answers here concern themselves with custom controls when the OP was asking about a standard checkbox?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is currently an issue with this and I reported it to Bootstrap. Until that's fixed do the following:

First of all, use the `form-control-lg` class. Once the issue is fixed using that class will be all you need.

Until the issue is fixed add the following css:

```
.custom-control-label::before, 
.custom-control-label::after {
    top: .8rem;
    width: 1.25rem;
    height: 1.25rem;
}
```

Here's a complete working code example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.custom-control-label::before, 
.custom-control-label::after {
top: .8rem;
width: 1.25rem;
height: 1.25rem;
}
</style>


<div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep. Works perfectly. Great job. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry mate. I didn't know this was important for You if I knew I'd do it couple days ago!

Comment: Question. Why this checkbox gets grey background?

Comment: Well, that's the default style from Bootstrap.

Comment: Well default checkbox has white background. Any idea how can we change 'big checkbox' bg to white?

Comment: With this particular style, the actual HTML checkbox is hidden and a Bootstrap style is applied to the whole thing. Post a new Bootstrap 4 question so that I can earn a few points answering that. :-)

Comment: Sure. There you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373119/change-bootstrap-4-checkbox-background-color

Comment: @WebDevBooster could you add a link to the issue in the Bootstrap tracker?

Comment: In my case (bootstrap vue rc12 + bootstrap 4.2.1) it was necessary to use `!important`

Comment: Update: The ability to change the size of a custom checkbox will probably be released in Bootstrap 5: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27803#issuecomment-450462476

Comment: Use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805394/how-to-change-size-of-icheck-checkbox-and-add-border-radius

Answer (score 23):

I've approached this a bit differently. Add the following to custom CSS.

```
.checkbox-1x {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
}
.checkbox-2x {
    transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
}
```

Then write the input like this: input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-1x"

Answer (score 17):

For Bootstrap 4.2.1 users this is how I got it to work.

I have introduced a new class `custom-control-lg` to handle it.

```css
.custom-control-lg .custom-control-label::before,
.custom-control-lg .custom-control-label::after {
    top: 0.1rem !important;
    left: -2rem !important;
    width: 1.25rem !important;
    height: 1.25rem !important;
}

.custom-control-lg .custom-control-label {
    margin-left: 0.5rem !important;
    font-size: 1rem !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="card m-3">
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="custom-control-lg custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox-large" type="checkbox"/>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox-large">
            Checkbox label for large input!
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox-small" type="checkbox"/>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox-small">
            Checkbox label for small input!
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to use it without label text?

Comment: @LuisRock Remove the text inside the <label ...>REMOVE THIS</label>

Comment: this messes with the checkbox position (at least in my case...).

Comment: Well, if want this to work without a label text, just place a `&nbsp` (Non-breaking Space HTML char) instead of it.

Answer (score 5):

If you import de scss from Bootstrap you can override the variable `$custom-control-indicator-size`.

```
$custom-control-indicator-size: 1.75rem;
```