# How can I change the "checked" background color of this Bootstrap 4 toggle switch?

Tags: css, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I can't figure out how to change the "checked" background color of this Bootstrap 4 toggle switch. It uses an extra library to toggle dark and light mode – [Here on github](https://github.com/coliff/dark-mode-switch) – but that works. All I want to do is change the background color of the active checkbox, which is by default blue. Does it default to blue from the Bootstrap CSS? This answer [Change Bootstrap 4 checkbox background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373119/change-bootstrap-4-checkbox-background-color) doesn't work for me; it changes the unchecked color, but I can't grep from it how to change the checked color.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/b82d9hep/4/)

My code here:

```css
.custom-control-input {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="darkSwitch" />
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="darkSwitch">Dark Mode</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply altered every possible properties that can affect the color like

> `.custom-control-input:checked`, `.custom-control-label::before`, `.custom-control-input:active` and `.custom-control-input:focus`

but you have to pay attention on altering `.custom-control-input::after` because it will destroy the pointer inside the toggle switch

### Example

```css
.custom-control-input:focus~.custom-control-label::before {
  border-color: red !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255, 47, 69, 0.25) !important;
}

.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
  border-color: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
}

.custom-control-input:active~.custom-control-label::before {
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

.custom-control-input:focus:not(:checked)~.custom-control-label::before {
  border-color: red !important;
}

.custom-control-input-green:not(:disabled):active~.custom-control-label::before {
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="darkSwitch" />
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="darkSwitch">Dark Mode</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great. Is there a way to get rid of the blue border when active? I don't see border CSS in Dev Tools.

Comment: Its not actually the `border` it is the `box-shadow` you can alter it if you want

Comment: If you want to the `box-shadow` to stay you can easily remove those `box-shadow` in my code but I don't think it is good idea because it will look somehow ugly

Comment: That's interesting; removing it in my site doesn't get rid of the blue box shadow.

Comment: Sorry I tried to understand the problem but I don't really understand what it is can you explain it to me

Comment: How do I change the "checked" box-shadow or border to red?

Comment: I tried all possible ways but here in the snippet it is still showing the blue `box-shadow` but in my chrome browser is working

Comment: Thanks, that's a mystery; I see it blue in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I'm sorry for your time now I realize that I was forgetting something but solved it

Answer (score 7):

Simply add this to your css file, or add it to your html file between `<style>` ... `</style>`, to change the background color of the switch - it also removes the blue circle and shadow. =]

```
.form-switch .form-check-input {
    height: 24px;
    width: 48px;
}
.form-switch .form-check-input:focus {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3e%3ccircle r='3' fill='rgba(0,0,0,0.25)'/></svg>");
}
.form-switch .form-check-input:checked {
    background-color: #30D158;
    border-color: #30D158;
    border: none;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3e%3ccircle r='3' fill='rgba(255,255,255,1.0)'/></svg>");
}
```